# Метать бисер: изначальный смысл

Tags: фразеология

В переносном значении "метать бисер" — делать что-то, что другие заведомо не оценят. Но что такое изначально означает "метать бисер"? Куда его надо метать и зачем?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, видимо, перед свиньями. Не оценят. Просто бисер здесь - парадоксальная замена зерна.

Answer (score 3):

Это иносказание из Евангелия. Говорится о том, что не каждый достоин труда проповедника.

> Не давайте святыни псам и не бросайте жемчуга вашего перед свиньями, чтобы они не попрали его ногами своими и, обратившись, не растерзали вас. "Мф.7:6"

Бисер (здесь, жемчуг) взят напрямую из церковно-славянского перевода.

Comment: Вопрос был не о смысле поговорки, а о процессе "метания бисера"